# How can I fix the BSOD KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

The software BlueScreenViews says the crash was caused by the driver RapportCerberus64_68261.sys however I could not identify a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my crash dump:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhz9685xx0qg86w/052514-29905-01.dmp

Comment: Boot into safe mode and remove Trusteer Rapport

Answer (score 0):

AMM

That is a component of Trusteer Rapaport.  I would remove it and use MSE in its place.  IMHO Rapaport is related to far too many BSOD'S